# How do I get the content type of a node entity from the $entity object?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm using [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8) to alter the values of nodes upon saving, but I only want to do this for a specific content type.

How do I check the content type of the $entity object?  I looked at the documentation for [class node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/class/Node/8) and [working with Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2124403), but all I found was how to get the entity type, not the content type.

Given a node `$entity` object, how can I check the content type?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you know that you have a node, then you can use `getType()`. If you don't know that, you can use he generic method `->bundle()`. Note that the second will return the entity type in case of an entity type that doesn't have bundles, like users.

Again, my standard reference to http://wizzlern.nl/sites/wizzlern.nl/files/artikel/drupal-content-entity-8.0.pdf, it contains both methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But is it possible to get the human readable value or it has to be str_replaced in order get there?

Answer (score 9):

Entity Type and bundle name are two things; usually you want to have both. You might e.g. have a media entity of the bundle "image".
Bundle names alone may not be unique, I think you could name a content type "gallery" and also a paragraph type "gallery" without getting a validation error.
So:

```
$entity->getEntityTypeId()
```

gives you the entity type: node, user, paragraph, media

```
$entity->bundle()
```

gives you the bundle name if you have one, could be "gallery" like described above.
As Berdir points out, getType() only works on nodes, so getEntityTypeId() would be a replacement for that that works on all entity types.